# Why does GDAL raster calculator treat no data as infinity?

Tags: qgis, gdal, raster-calculator

I am using GDAL raster calculator in QGIS. I was getting some funny results where my input raster had "no data" so I ran some tests.

(5<no data) gives 1

(5>no data) gives 0

10 - no data = no data

1/nodata = 2.9e-39

From this I deduce that "no data" values are treated as infinite. Is this correct? I can't find anywhere in the documentation which describes the treatment of "no data" values. This interpretation does not explain why addition or subtraction gives "no data" as the result.

Comment: I think it treats is a `NaN`

Comment: OK, so is NaN treated as infinite?

Comment: because you aren't supposed to do maths with NaN

Comment: @IanTurton - that seems completely correct - however, what then 1/nodata or 5<no data does not result in no data as well, but returns a number?

Comment: that's actually a `True` and a `False`

Comment: For 0/1 OK - but what about `1/nodata = 2.9e-39` ?

Comment: I guess one thing confusing me is why 5>NaN is different to 5<NaN ? I could understand these both returning false. But the results suggest that NaN is in someway bigger than 5?

Comment: There may be some useful information in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1893.